# Trouble reading FITS with Mathematica 12

Tags: image-processing, import, fits-format

I've been using *Mathematica* to process FITS for years, but it has changed in version 12. `Import` now yields an `Association` rather than an `Image`. OK, extract item 1 from the `Association`, that's an `Image`. But it isn't right.

```
ImageData[Import["test.fits"][[1]]]
```

yields a matrix full of tiny numbers like `2.81374*10^-307`. This is impossible. The header has:

> BITPIX  =                   32 / array data type
>
> BSCALE  =                    1
>
> BZERO   =           2147483648

This is the conventional declaration of 32 bit unsigned integers. Apparently, these are misinterpreted as floating point.

Is this a bug, or have I missed another change?

Here's the [test file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o70gpavh9yrcgfj/test.fits?dl=0)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FITS

Comment: could you possibly share your "test.fits" file? Thanks

Comment: @Manuel does this work?[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o70gpavh9yrcgfj/test.fits?dl=0)

Comment: Looks like there is a response: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1853359